# Как отцентровать блок по нижнему краю родительского блока

Tags: html, css, css3

У меня есть 1 общий родительский блок:

.partners-bl-and-info-ct{

}

В нем есть 2 блока: Логотип и правый блок с контактной информацией.

Мне надо блок с логотипом цетровать вертикально по центру родительского контейнера, т.е **partners-bl-and-info-ct**

Вот css:

```
.partners-bl-and-info-ct{

    }

    .partners-big-logo{
      width: 240px;
      height: 192px;
      float:left;
      margin-right: 60px;
    }

    .partners-info-block{
      float:left;
      width: 400px;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке будет более понятно, что логотип "Тамара" должен быть по центру высоты блока с текстовой информацией

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может флексбоксом?

```
.partners-bl-and-info-ct{
  display: flex;
  // align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.partners-big-logo{
  width: 240px;
  height: 192px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.partners-info-block{
  width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Подходит! спасибо большое!

Comment: Не подскажите еще вариант, как отцентровать partners-big-logo по низу родительского контейнера? так как если применить align-items:bottom то это не срабатывает

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wgje5r1j/

Comment: Советую рассмотреть вопрос изучения флексбокса... на css-tricks есть хорошая статья. Удачи!